# How can my system have two mountpoints?

Tags: boot, grub2, 15.10

I had Ubuntu 14.04 but accidentaly I upgraded it to 16.04, after It my OS was broken, so I decide to format my disk and install stable Ubuntu 15.10.

During the installation from usb, I was informed by the system that there is a problem with `apt` and after, the `grub` rescue shell was loaded.

I tried to repair it and I ran the Boot Repair tool from a Live CD. Unfortunately, it stack on 'Purge kernels then reinstall sda6(ins).'

In GParted I see: [image]

Is it ok that there are two mountpoints? Should I wait or cancel this Boot Repair and try it from the command line?

Comment: Boot-Repair mounts partitions, and that is the mount from Boot-Repair. Do not turn off system, but unmount everything or you may corrupt system. If Boot-Repair has hung for some reason like Internet not working, then Holding down Ctrl+Alt and SysRq (which is the Print Screen key) while slowly typing REISUB.

Comment: Thank you. I was waiting near 1 hour and still nothing. This orange bar is moving all the time but nothing happen. Should I stop this app or wait more? 
http://i.snag.gy/KIame.jpg

Comment: Do you have a good Internet connection, best to have hard wired Internet not Wifi. Boot-Repair is usually the better or easier way to repair grub issues.

Answer (score 0):

Seems some basic problems according to me:
/dev/sda6 should be mounted as '/' On this one you should install Ubuntu
/dev/sda5 is linux swap partition
/dev/sda3 is ntfs(windows partition) - why it is mounted on Linux?

Am i missing something. Could you please elaborate what you are trying to do? This may not be an answer but could help you in terms of understanding what you are doing and why?

May be start all over again and install it fresh.

Comment: After installation of Ubuntu 15.10 I am not able to run in normal way my laptop,  grub_rescue terminal appears. Using 'ls' command I found that sda6 is ext and I tried to mount it. As I understand my grub is broken and I would like to repair it.